# AngularJS - Configure application to store API URL's

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using my custom **app.config.js** file to configure API end point and other URL's as shown below using environment variable.

```
angular.module('api-config', []).constant('ENV',
{
    name: 'My Project Name',
    apiEndPoint: 'http://SOMEIP/gateway/',
    apiListUser: '/user',
    apiUser: '/user/{:id}'

});
```

**Controller**

```
var servicePath = ENV.apiEndPoint;
var listUserApi = ENV.apiListUser;

return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: servicePath + listUserApi
})
```

Drawbacks of above approach

> 1. External developer/consultant now has access to all private configuration data that is stored in config.
> 2. Not scalable as fixed config prevents deployments tools from dynamically scaling and configuring application as needed.

**Need to perform below**

- Able to deploy AngularJS application in different environments
  (staging, production, etc.) with different configurations without
  changing the AngularJS application code.
- Able to share AngularJS application code with external parties at any
  given moment without leaking any confidential configuration details. Although I'm separating all configuration details in separate file
  **app.config.js**, is it the best possible way for strict separation of config from code ?
- If any developer views the source and open **app.config.js** file,
     it can have my API(IP) endpoint and all the URL's that has been used
     in app. How do I avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it is, we have a configuration file (app.config, defaults.config etc). When we load the application, we call a web api which reads this config file and returns a JSON. We then persist this object in a service. So, we now have all the configuration settings in angular as an angular service. This solves all the problems that you have mentioned.

Comment: It would be great if you post relevant code to get an overall picture of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{configData.key1}}

  <script>
    (function() {
      var app = angular.module("app", [])

      /* run function gets config.js file on load
       */
      .run(['urlFactory', function(urlFactory) {
        urlFactory.getConfig(window.__env);
      }])

      .controller("myCtrl", function(APIFactory, urlFactory, $scope) {
        
        $scope.configData = urlFactory.configData;
        APIFactory.proveAPIfactHaveData();
        

      }).factory("urlFactory", function() {

        var configData = {
          key1: null,
          key2: null
        };
        /* this factory function makes it available to every where*/
        function getConfig(data) {
          angular.extend(configData, data);
        }

        var service = {
          configData: configData,
          getConfig: getConfig,
        }
        return service;

      }).factory("APIFactory", function(urlFactory) {

        var service = {
          proveAPIfactHaveData: proveAPIfactHaveData,
        }
        return service;

        function proveAPIfactHaveData() {
          alert(JSON.stringify(urlFactory.configData));
        }

      });
    }());
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

your config.js file

```
(function (window) {
  window.__env = window.__env || {};
    window.__env.key1       =   "key1";
    window.__env.key2       =   "key2";
}(this));
```